# Select between two dates - I get always Runtime Error 3464

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

I'm using Access and VBA to read some tables via DAO. I would like to read everything in my table that is between date1 and date2. I have something like this:

```
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
```

'...

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ImportData between '" & date1 & "' AND '" & date2 & "'"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL) 'Runtime Error 3464
```

I just get a Runtime Error `3464 Data type mismatch` Not sure why, if I put strSQL in a MsgBox the query I get is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ImportData between '15.03.2014' AND '11.03.2014'
```

The column 'ImportData' in my Table is also Date/Time Type, so why is this not working? Also tried without `'` or using `<>` and so on, that is not helping. Any ideas? Thank you

Edit:

If I would use:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ImportData between #" & date1 & "# AND #" & date2 & "#"
```

Then I get `Runtime Error 3075` - Syntaxerror in Date

Comment: If ImportData is date/time and not just date, then it's likely that it can't be compared to a date value. Try converting `date1` and `date2` to datetime.

Comment: I'm not sure you can concatenate a date with a string like that.

Comment: @mjsqu I'm not that good with VBA, but as I see there is no DateTime, just as Date type for a variable. I can change my column in access explicit to a dd/dd/yyyy format but the error message is the same :/

Comment: It's a question of the datatypes in the SQL not the VBA, the query is where the error occurs

Comment: try this one: `"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ImportData BETWEEN #" & Format$(date2, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND #" & Format$(date1, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"`

Comment: @simoco Thank you, this is working without any error!

Answer (score 2):

For date values, use # instead of the single quote:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ImportData between #" & date1 & "# AND #" & date2 & "#"
```

Comment: Hi, with that I get not a Runtime Error 3075 - Syntaxerror in Date